# Can Bootstraps' Scrollspy be used on Angular 4?

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, angular

I want to use Bootstrap's Scrollspy in my Angular 4 application, but It doesn't seem to work. I tried including jquery in the project but still no success.

If re-built it just like it is shown on Bootstraps' demo page. When I click one of the items, the `href` tries to load the anchor as a new site and I get a 404 Error.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how to integrate Bootstrap scrollspy, but you could rollout your own solution by listening to the scroll event directly on the component template:

```
<div (document:scroll)="scroll($event)"></div>
```

Then, to check if the component is off the browser canvas, you can:

```
this.el.nativeElement.getBoundingClientRect().top
```

`this.el` is a reference to the component DOM element and needs to be injected on the component constructor:

```
constructor(el: ElementRef){}
```